# Store arrays of data into a single array using loop on laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel-4, bulkinsert

I was stuck on figuring how to store my arrays of data into a single one so I can insert it on the table using eloquent. I am using a javascript to add dynamic rows. Here's the js:

```
$(function(){
var rowCount = document.getElementById('tblContacts').rows.length - 1 ;
var rowArrayId = rowCount ;

function addRow(){

    $("#tblContacts tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text' name='product[" + rowArrayId + "][name]' class='form-control'/></td>"+
        "<td><textarea name='product[" + rowArrayId + "][description]' class='form-control' rows='1'></textarea></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' name='product[" + rowArrayId + "][quantity]' class='form-control'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' name='product[" + rowArrayId + "][price]' class='form-control'/></td>"+
        "<td><button class='btnRemoveRow btn btn-danger'>Remove</button></td>"+
        "</tr>");

    $(".btnRemoveRow").bind("click", removeRow);

rowArrayId = rowArrayId + 1; };


function removeRow(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    par.remove();
};
});
```

and here's my html file

```
<tr>
<td><input type='text' name='product[0][name]' class="form-control"/></td>
<td><textarea name='product[0][description]' class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea></td>
<td><input type='text' name='product[0][quantity]' class="form-control"/></td>
<td><input type='text' name='product[0][price]' class="form-control"/></td>
<td><button class="btnRemoveRow btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
 </tr>
$(".btnRemoveRow").bind("click", removeRow);
$("#btnAddRow").bind("click", addRow);
```

and in my controller when I tried to use

```
$input = Input::get('product');
dd($input);
```

I got these result:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'first product' (length=13)
  'description' => string 'first product description' (length=25)
  'quantity' => string '10' (length=2)
  'price' => string '15' (length=2)
1 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string '2nd product ' (length=12)
  'description' => string '2nd product description' (length=23)
  'quantity' => string '20' (length=2)
  'price' => string '20' (length=2)
2 => 
array (size=4)
  'name' => string '3rd product ' (length=12)
  'description' => string '3rd product description' (length=23)
  'quantity' => string '25' (length=2)
  'price' => string '30' (length=2)
```

I learned it from here:
 [Generating New Array from Laravel 4 Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834200/generating-new-array-from-laravel-4-input)

my question is how can i put these arrays into a single array to come up like these code

```
$insert = array();

foreach($tab as $key => $value)
{
$insert[] = array(
    'id_reservation' => $reservation_id,
    'produit_id' => $key,
    'quantite' => $value
);
}

DB::table('products')->insert($insert);
```

I also get the above code from here: [[SOLVED] fluent query builder multiple insert with a foreach](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=2994)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert multiple values by constructing an associative array wherein the keys are column names and the values are, well, the values.  It isn't obvious why you are confused, since the example you provide is pretty much spot on:

```
$inserts = array();
foreach ( $input as $v ) {
    $inserts[] = array('name' => $v['name'], 'quantity' => $v['quantity']);
}
DB::table('your_table')->insert($inserts);
```

Comment: it worked like charm! Totally saves my day! Thank you very much for the help :)